# Should a user's passwords be limited to a specific character set or strength?

Tags: passwords

Just finishing up my signup/login/logout etc... type functionality of my site and I was curious. Should a user be forced to have a password that meets a certain strength or character set?

Example one, forcing them to use a alphanumeric password of length > 8

Example two, only allowing them to use alphanumeric characters and some special characters (ie: !@#$%).

The first example is obviously a good thing to enforce on a sensitive site such as Banking but I can't think of a good reason to limit a user's password characters. As long as the string is cleaned for sql injection, it shouldn't matter what they use character wise right?

**EDIT**

And of course the password is being HASHED

Comment: Some bank sites restrict the passwords only numbers, so users may enter the password by dial pad for telephone transactions. But personally, I don't like to restrict the character set, because I'm using site password generator.

Comment: At least, check if the users submitted password checks out against the top 100 passwords. I suggest enforcing special characters, but it depends on what kind of site you're establishing and the barrier to entry you require. Security is not easy, but at times it's necessary.

Comment: My emphasis on secure hashing is not just for you, but for everyone else who comes across this as well.  There are still too many (read: `> 1`) websites that email users their actual passwords when asked to.

Comment: @Slaks - And lets admit that the complexity of the login is often directly related to the ease of signin and use of the service, which means that security is not often the (or even a) priority.

Comment: I've always felt that an easy login matched with instant text notifying user's of their account login provided more security than enforcing a hard to remember password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Please***, don't tell me what characters I can't use in my passwords.

You should support the full range of Unicode code points in passwords, with the possible exception of ASCII control characters (`\0` – `\0x20`).

It is your responsibility to make sure that any normal character will work in a password, including spaces, quotes, and backslashes.

Passwords cannot be vulnerable to SQL injection, since **the database must never see the actual password**.  You should hash and salt your passwords before they get anywhere near the database.  (use bcrypt)

---

*Minimum* complexity requirements are a double-edged sword.  If you require a password that is too complicated for your users to remember, they will end up writing it down somewhere, and probably somewhere close at hand.
At the very least, you should require 6 characters and at least two of `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, or any other character.

Comment: No special characters? Tsk, tsk! :P

Comment: @Jared: I said it's a bare minimum.  You should consider the risks involved, and the sophistication of your users, before setting your actual minimums.

Comment: And I did say :P right? I know plenty who would complain, and note my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection should not really matter: you should be hashing it before it ever reaches the DB.  There really is no reason to limit the character set.